# Write a function intreverse(n) that takes as input a positive integer n and returns the integer obtained by reversing the digits in n

Tags: python, reverse

What changes should I make in the code so that when the program compiles and runs i will have to type function to get the output? How do I call the function in the console?

```
def intreverse(n):
    last=0
    rev=0
    while ( n > 0 ):
        last = n % 10
        n = n // 10
        rev = (rev * 10) + last
    return rev

x=int(input("Enter number: "))
r=intreverse(x)
print(r)

#expected input: 
#>> intreverse(123)

#expected output:
   #321
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to have the function run while in a REPL? Can't you just get rid of the part after the function definition?

Comment: I want to make changes to this code such that when I run this code I will have to type function name(intreverse) followed with arguement (123). What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

```
def intreverse(n):
    last=0
    rev=0
    while ( n > 0 ):
        last = n % 10
        n = n // 10
        rev = (rev * 10) + last
    return rev
```

You will need to use the print function from the command line and to see the results as your function is returning a value.

```
print(intreverse(123))
```

edit: OP's comment below:

```
def intreverse():
    n = input()
    last=0
    rev=0
    while ( n > 0 ):
        last = n % 10
        n = n // 10
        rev = (rev * 10) + last
    print(rev)
```

Run these in the command line.

```
intreverse()
123
```

This is a poor programming practice, but it is what you wanted. A function should return a value that is in turn used somewhere else, not just printed out.

Comment: I want to make changes to this code such that when I run this code I will have to type function name(intreverse) followed with arguement (123). What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't run the function; you run the program from the command line, such as:

```
python my_file.py
```

If you want to run from the interactive console, then you need to enter all of your code in the console, just as you see them in your posting.  Once you have the function defined in the console, you can enter the line

```
>> intereverse(123)
```

You should have full usage instructions in your class materials.